# span not working on Bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button over which I want to have a bubble with a number, much like a notification that appears on an app icon in an iphone.

My mark up for the button is:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning view-sl-btn" type="button"><span class="notification, red">6</span>View Shortlist</button>
```

And the Css for the span is:

```
.btn.span {
    position: absolute;

    background-color: #f56c7e;

    border: 1px solid #ce4f5e;
    padding: 2px 5px 1px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-top: -16px;

    border-radius: 100px;

    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-size: 11px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -o-box-shadow:      inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    box-shadow:         inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
.btn.span.red {
    background-color: #f56c7e;
    border-color: #ce4f5e;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Not the problem here but if you want to target the class `notification` ever you will need to remove the comma in your class attribute `class="notification, red"` should be `class="notification red"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your CSS declaration:

```
.btn.span
```

(Would apply styles to all elements with the 'btn' class AND the 'span' class.)

```
<div class="btn span" />
```

You want this:

```
.btn span
```

(Which would style all `span`s that are descendants of an element with the 'btn' class.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead

```
.btn span
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, .btn span is the proper syntax for the css since span is an HTML tag. The use of the period before the span would suggest it is a css class, which it is not.